# Ruby equivalent for C "signed long long"

Tags: ruby, long-integer

is there an equivalent in Ruby for the C type "signed long long"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No; Ruby has automatic conversion to large integer objects (Bignum) to avoid overflow. There are no types for integers with specific sizes.

Comment: Alternatively: "__Yes__; Ruby has automatic conversion to large integer objects, so any Ruby integer can represent a 'signed long long'" :)

Comment: @dbenhur: well, except that it won't overflow to a negative value when it gets too big (granted, relying on this behavior for a `long long` in C is probably a sign that you're doing something ugly).